# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 on dell precision 3800

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, dell

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 on my precision 3800 but I am encountering huge difficulties. My problem is that the USB pendrive I created does not load at all the installer.

I disabled fast boot, secure boot but still no boot from the USB drive.

I used legacy boot and the initial boot menu popped up but then none of the options were accessible.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Have you tried checking the md5sum with the [Ubuntu hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 (or 8.1) **needs** to be properly shutdown, so Windows can unmount the disc.

And also, if you have a problem with your USB pendrive, you need to Eject and then plug it in again when you install Linux on it.It needs to be named like this: "Install Ubuntu"

**If you can not** still install, try to search for a new version of your BIOS.

Comment: Updating the UEFI/BIOS was the key. Now it runs smoothly